# Openshift 302 mangling

Tags: openshift, url-routing

I have a application on [Openshift Online](https://www.openshift.com/) at `http://rsdbtest-abex.rhcloud.com/`. It has aliases and matching `CNAME`s for the following domains:

`http://rsdb-test.tk/`,`http://www.rsdb-test.tk/`,`http://sub.rsdb-test.tk/`,`http://sub.sub.rsdb-test.tk/`

The server is set to respond to `/` express's request object. Any other path generates a 302 with the `Location` header set to the path, so in theory a request to `http://rsdb-test.tk/http://sub.rsdb-test.tk` would take you to `http://sub.rsdb-test.tk`. This works locally, however the location after exiting OpenShift's router is `http://rsdb-test.tk`. The domain is replaced with the request's domain. If you run the server locally or curl from inside the gear the `Location` header is still correct, indicating my code is not the problem.

Is there a way to work around this behavior and redirect to any domain, or do I have to use `<meta>` to redirect?

The server listening is a simple express server:

```
var express = require("express");
var util=require("util");

var e = process.env;
var config = {
    IP:e.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP||"",
    Port:e.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT||80,
    TrustProxy:true,
}

var app = express();
app.set("trust proxy",config.TrustProxy)


app.use(function(req,res,next){
    var path=req.path.substr(1);
    if(path){
        res.redirect(302,path);
    }else{
        res.send(util.inspect(req));
    }
});

app.listen(config.Port,config.IP,function(){
    console.log("Started");
});
```

Comment: I just tried http://rsdb-test.tk/http://sub.rsdb-test.tk in Firefox and it works as you described.

Comment: It seems to be intermittent. As of writing `http://rsdb-test.tk/http://sub.rsdb-test.tk/http://sub.sub.rsdb-test.tk/` redirects incorrectly, dropping the sub domain again.

Comment: So it seems that if the `Location` header ends with a `/` the location gets mangled,otherwise it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is directly related to how ProxyPassReverse works in Apache.

Every application in OpenShift is defined with at least two ProxyPassReverse directives -- one for the internal IP address, and one for the application FQDN:

```
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.12.219.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://rsdbtest-abex.rhcloud.com/
```

In your case, you have several more, one for each alias you have defined:

```
ProxyPassReverse / http://rsdb-test.tk/
ProxyPassReverse / http://sub.rsdb-test.tk/
ProxyPassReverse / http://sub.sub.rsdb-test.tk/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.rsdb-test.tk/
```

Anytime your application returns a redirect to one of these hosts, Apache rewrites the host portion to match the host header used in the original request.  So, let's take this example:

```
http://rsdb-test.tk/http://sub.rsdb-test.tk/http://sub.sub.rsdb-test.tk/
```

You first make a request like:

```
GET /http://sub.rsdb-test.tk/http://sub.sub.rsdb-test.tk/ HTTP/1.1
Host: rsdb-test.tk
```

Your app returns:

```
http://sub.rsdb-test.tk/http://sub.sub.rsdb-test.tk/
```

but the ProxyPassReverse configuration rewrites this to:

```
http://rsdb-test.tk/http://sub.sub.rsdb-test.tk/
```

Next you follow that redirect:

```
GET /http://sub.sub.rsdb-test.tk/ HTTP/1.1
Host: rsdb-test.tk
```

Your application returns:

```
http://sub.sub.rsdb-test.tk/
```

but again, ProxyPassReverse rewrites this to:

```
http://rsdb-test.tk/
```

When you remove the trailing slash, what happens is that the second redirect has an empty "path" element, so the "ProxyPassReverse / ..." rules don't match it anymore, which is an unfortunate inconsistency.  Even when it does work, though, I don't think it's doing exactly what you expect, as it's making two requests to rsdb-test.tk followed by a request to sub.sub.rsdb-test.tk (whereas you were probably expecting rsdb-test.tk, then sub.rsdb-test.tk, then sub.sub.rsdb-test.tk).

In general, the redirects appear to be working as expected, and there's not any simple way for us to remove the ProxyPassReverse settings from your application. Let me know if that explanation makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I was suspecting it was ProxyPassReverse but I couldn't find docs on how the routing layer worked. For now I have swapped to a meta refresh, which works for my case, but it would be nice to have a way to bypass this when meta refresh isn't a option.